# Android StrictMode doesn't kill the app and report errors in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, performance

I am trying to use strict mode in android so I want the app to be turned off in case I do time consuming things on the main thread. This does not seem to happen I don't get any errors or warnings in the logcat in eclipse.

What do I need to change so StrictMode will kill the app and give me feedback in the logcat of where this violation occured? What would I need to do if I had a lot of fragments and activities in my project in order to make it work for a bigger project?

I have written the following code in my mainActivity:

```
             public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


             StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                     .detectDiskReads()
                     .detectDiskWrites()
                     .detectNetwork()   
                     .penaltyLog()
                     .build());
             StrictMode.setVmPolicy(new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder()
                     .detectLeakedSqlLiteObjects()
                     .detectLeakedClosableObjects()
                     .penaltyLog()
                     .penaltyDeath()
                     .build());

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        int disturb=0;

        while(disturb<10000){
            disturb += 2;
            SystemClock.sleep(300);
           }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `penaltyDeath()` instead of `penaltyLog()` in first builder initialization.

Comment: It does make things better because the app is killed and the log is shown. However, the row where the error occurs (according to the log) is "super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);" and not the row on which the time consuming while loop is. Why is that? BTW I also removed the setVmPolicy part since it didn't seem to make any difference. Is that wrong?

Comment: To be fair, I've never used penaltyLog(), so can't comment on this. Regarding the VmPolicy, yes, probably ThreadPolicy is enough for your use case. The problem is that you're missing penaltyDeath() call and this is why the app doesn't crash when blocking the UI thread.

Comment: I am using the penaltyDeath() but the correct row number is not revealed for where the app should be killed.